# Concatenate multiple files under subdirectories

Tags: linux, command-line, shell-script, scripting

My directory structure is given below

`x:\Project_2012-158A\Sample_4041`

```
SampleSheet.csv
4041_CGTACG_L002_R1_001.fastq
4041_CGTACG_L002_R2_001.fastq
4041_CGTACG_L006_R2_001.fastq
4041_CGTACG_L006_R1_001.fastq
```

`x:\Project_2012-158A\Sample_4027`

```
SampleSheet.csv
4027_TAGCTT_L002_R2_001.fastq
4027_TAGCTT_L006_R1_001.fastq
4027_TAGCTT_L002_R1_001.fastq
4027_TAGCTT_L006_R2_001.fastq
```

`x:\Project_2012-158A\Sample_D425`

```
SampleSheet.csv
D425_ACTGAT_L008_R2_001.fastq
D425_ACTGAT_L008_R1_001.fastq
D425_ACTGAT_L004_R2_001.fastq
D425_ACTGAT_L004_R1_001.fastq
```

I want to concatenate the files with "R1" and "R2" separately for every sample. 
I know

```
cat file1.fastq file2.fastq > concatenation.fastq
```

will give concatenate but how do I do that for all the sudirectories with single script?

Comment: Backslashes and drive letters ... are you on Windows?  Unless you are asking about something like [cygwin](http://cygwin.com/), you are probably on the wrong site.

Comment: No. This directory structure I created using windows. I want to perform my tasks on Linux.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
cd /path/to/Project_2012-158A &&
for dir in Sample*/; do
    for r in R1 R2; do
        outfile=${dir%/}_${r}.fastq
        glob=*_${r}_*.fastq
        cat "$dir"/$glob > "$dir/$outfile" &&
        rm -f "$dir"/$glob
    done
done
```

Comment: Thanks @jw013. I'm new here. I wish I could vote you up.

Comment: Note that except with zsh, that would create empty files for Sample directories that don't have _R1_ or _R2_ files.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas You are right.  If the OP wants, it'd be trivial to check for and remove the empty files.  I also considered adding lines to remove the original files but eventually decided not to unless the OP specifically asks for it.  For now, I just gave a simplest example.

Comment: @jw013 Is there anyways I could save the file names with SampleXXX_R1.fastq and SampleXXX_R2.fastq for every samples? and also delete the original files?

Comment: @jw013 I'm getting this error 
Sample_1008//Sample_1008//Sample_1008/_R1.fastq: No such file or directory
concatinate_final.sh: line 6: Sample_1008//Sample_1008//Sample_1008/_R2.fastq: No such file or directory
concatinate_final.sh: line 6: Sample_1009//Sample_1009//Sample_1009/_R1.fastq: No such file or directory
concatinate_final.sh: line 6: Sample_1009//Sample_1009//Sample_1009/_R2.fastq: No such file or directory

Comment: glob=*_${r}_*.fastq  .. could this be subject to wildcard expansion?

Comment: @jw013  
nope still getting this error concatinate_final.sh: line 6: Sample_1008//Sample_1008/_R1.fastq: No such file or directory concatinate_final.sh: line 6: Sample_1008//Sample_1008/_R2.fastq: No such file or directory concatinate_final.sh: line 6: Sample_1009//Sample_1009/_R1.fastq: No such file or directory concatinate_final.sh: line 6: Sample_1009//Sample_1009/_R2.fastq: No such file or directory

Comment: @jw013 I want the output to be "Sample_1008_R1.fastq" not "Sample_1008/_R1.fastq"

Comment: @jw013 Perfect. It worked. Thanks a million :)

Comment: @Jana Don't forget to mark an answer (click on the checkmark) as accepted if your question has been satisfactorily answered.

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
cat ./*/*R2* > result
```

`*` - match everything

Be aware that this will get every occurrence of `R2` in the filename.

Comment: Thanks @week, but this concatenate all files with R2 into one file. I don't want that. I wan't the files to be concatenated under "every" sub directory. ex: under 'Sample_4041' directory all files with R2 should be concatenated and the same applies to other sub directories as well. At the end I'll have only two files under each sample sub directory

Comment: @Jana add that to your question - it's an important part of the requirement.