# combining two files to a single file

Tags: files, cat

I have a folder with 700 files (350 individuals, for each I have 2 files R1 and R2),

```
HI.2622.001.Index_16.ED16_KS1W9-3_342_R1.fastq.gz_matches_default.fit_ID_90.fit_ID90_e
HI.2622.001.Index_16.ED16_KS1W9-3_342_R2.fastq.gz_matches_default.fit_ID_90.fit_ID90_e
HI.2622.001.Index_19.ED18_ND1W27-2_288_R1.fastq.gz_matches_default.fit_ID_90.fit_ID90_e
HI.2622.001.Index_19.ED18_ND1W27-2_288_R2.fastq.gz_matches_default.fit_ID_90.fit_ID90_e
HI.2622.001.Index_21.ED20_SD1W11-7_237_R1.fastq.gz_matches_default.fit_ID_90.fit_ID90_e
HI.2622.001.Index_21.ED20_SD1W11-7_237_R2.fastq.gz_matches_default.fit_ID_90.fit_ID90_e
HI.2622.001.Index_2.ED2_KS2W24-7_43_R1.fastq.gz_matches_default.fit_ID_90.fit_ID90_e
HI.2622.001.Index_2.ED2_KS2W24-7_43_R2.fastq.gz_matches_default.fit_ID_90.fit_ID90_e
```

There are 2 files per each individual (R1,R2),like this

```
HI.2622.001.Index_16.ED16_KS1W9-3_342_R1.fastq.gz_matches_default.fit_ID_90.fit_ID90_e
HI.2622.001.Index_16.ED16_KS1W9-3_342_R2.fastq.gz_matches_default.fit_ID_90.fit_ID90_e
```

I want to combine the R1 and R2 file for each individual. if there is only 1 individual with 2 files I could simply do

```
cat HI.2622.001.Index_16.ED16_KS1W9-3_342_R1.fastq.gz_matches_default.fit_ID_90.fit_ID90_e  HI.2622.001.Index_16.ED16_KS1W9-3_342_R2.fastq.gz_matches_default.fit_ID_90.fit_ID90_e > HI.2622.001.Index_16.ED16_KS1W9-3_342_all
```

But as I said there 700 files and it takes lots of time if I want to combine R1and R2 file for each individual seperatly. Is there any way that I could do it for instance through looping? each individual has a different ID. I have file which contains the ID of each individual

```
head inds.names
HI.2622.001.Index_16.ED16_KS1W9-3_342
HI.2622.001.Index_19.ED18_ND1W27-2_288
HI.2622.001.Index_21.ED20_SD1W11-7_237
HI.2622.001.Index_2.ED2_KS2W24-7_43
```

Comment: Similar, but not an exact duplicate, of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94164/concatenate-files-in-multiple-matching-subdirectories and of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55731/concatenate-multiple-files-under-subdirectories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be fairly straightforward with [parameter expansion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion) e.g.

```
for f in HI.2622.001.Index_*_R1.fastq.gz_matches_default.fit_ID_90.fit_ID90_e; do
  cat "$f" "${f/R1/R2}" > "${f%%_R1*}_all"
done
```